# Retrieving JSON from cookies

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json, cookies, ruby-on-rails-4

My cookie is set as follows

```
cookies[:cart] = "[{"id":"23","amount":"9"},{"id":"37","amount":"4"}]"
```

`cookies[:cart]` returns `[{"id":"23"`

and calling `.each` on cookies produces this abomination:

```
["cart", "[{\"id\":\"23\""] ["\"amount\":\"9\"}", nil] ["{\"id\":\"37\"", nil] ["\"amount\":\"4\"}]", nil]
```

I'm totally lost and can't really figure out what is going on (I suspect the `','` is doing some funny stuff).

So my questions are:

- Is there a way around this?
- Am I doing something terribly wrong by storing JSON in cookies?
- if point_2 then, What would be a better way? (I'm mainly storing with Javascript and reading with RoR, and I figured parsing with the build in JSON functions would be easier.)

Comment: Is that exactly what it produced or have you typed it in by hand? What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Your hash looks like this in ruby: `[{id:23,amount:9},{id:37,amount:4}]`

To turn it into json use `[{id:23,amount:9},{id:37,amount:4}].to_json` which will give you:

`"[{\"id\":23,\"amount\":9},{\"id\":37,\"amount\":4}]"`

Comment: the hash above is generated with javascript and stored as a cookie

Answer (score 0):

Still not sure if what I'm doing is the right way to handle such situations but my supposed work around is as follows:

I call `.replace(/,/g, '.');` in Javascript before storing the cookie, and I call `.replace(/\./g, ',');`  after retrieving it in Javascript and `.gsub(/\./, ",")` after retrieving it in RoR.

Seems like a horrible workaround for me, but for the time being it is an OK solution for me as I'm 100% certain that there will never be dots used in this cookie.

Comment: In JavaScript there is the JSON object which allows you to `JSON.parse` or `JSON.stringify` to handle this kind of work.

Comment: @Ahmed, that is exactly what I used and the sole reason why I'm storing JSON in cookies. Both ruby and javascript have built in methods to parse JSON in both ways.